# fast insertion of many entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to insert a List of 170.000 entities into my local installed MySQL 8.0 database using Hibernate 4.2.
Currently I'm doing this via the Session#save method. But inserting those many entities lasts so long. So is there a possibility to do this faster?

```
for (Agagf x : list) {
    create(x);
}

// ------------------------

    public static void create(Object obj) throws DatabaseException {
        Session hsession = null;

        try {
            hsession = SqlDataHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction htransaction = hsession.beginTransaction();
            hsession.save(obj);
            htransaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        } finally {
            if (hsession != null)
                hsession.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move the transaction around the `for loop`. The transaction are really slowing down hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this article on Hibernate page: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html

According to them, you would need something like this:

```
create(list);

// ------------------------

public static void create(List<Object> objList) throws DatabaseException {
  Session hsession = null;

  try {
    hsession = SqlDataHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction htransaction = hsession.beginTransaction();

    int count = 0;
    for(Agagf x: objList) {
        hsession.save(obj);
        if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            hsession.flush();
            hsession.clear();
            count = 0;
        }
    }
  } catch (HibernateException ex) {
    throw new DatabaseException(ex);
  } finally {
    htransaction.commit();
    if (hsession != null) {
      hsession.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the configuration to enable batch processing:

if you are undertaking batch processing you will need to enable the use of JDBC 
batching. This is absolutely essential if you want to achieve optimal 
performance. Set the JDBC batch size to a reasonable number (10-50, for example):

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
```

Edit: In your case, play with the batch size to better fit your volume. Just remember to make the same size in both configuration and if statement for flush.

Comment: The commit is the cost one and takes long, that is why it happens only at the end as well.